# Plotting polygons in Python using GeoPandas and quantile scheme

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas

I have a data frame with latitude, longitude and annual consumption data. I am trying to plot the annual consumption data using GeoPandas with a quantile scheme by making a polygon column. I followed the following tutorial.
[enter link description here](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/choropleths.html)

I used the latitude and longitude data to make polygon shapes using the following code.

```
full_dataframe["geometry"] = Polygon(list(zip(full_dataframe["long"], full_dataframe["lat"])))

merged2 = GeoDataFrame(full_dataframe)

merged2.plot(column='annual_consume', scheme='quantiles', k=4, edgecolor='k', 
             cmap='OrRd', legend=True,
             legend_kwds={'loc': 'center left', 'bbox_to_anchor':(1,0.5)})
```

My data frame looks like below
[image]

The issue is, when I plot it, it looks like a big mess of interconnecting points. The boundaries are not seperated.

[image]

I want a similar boundary separation like the tutorial based on longitude and latitude data.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a bit more insight about your data structure? For example, you mention that your `full_dataframe` has points, not polygons. What do those points represent? More specifically: how do the points in your `full_dataframe` object relate to the polygons in the figure you pasted at the bottom of your question?

Comment: can you check the question again now? I hope it is more clear what I am asking.

Comment: Hi there! It helps a little bit, but not much. My main question remains: what is the relationship between the **points** inside the `full_dataframe` object and the **polygons** we see at the image on the bottom? In the tutorial you linked to, they don't construct the polygons from lon-lat coordinates. Instead, the polygons already existed in the geodataframe from the start.

Comment: It seems you used the functions ``Polygon`` which takes the values (in your cases, the coordinates) as NODES to create polygons. I think you are looking to creat Thiessen polygons...Take a look on how to do it